How to find the annihilator of a module/how to determine the torsion module
Given a left $R$-module $M$. Given a subset of $S\subset M$.
What are related theorems concerning the annihilator of $S\subset M$ that can be used in practice? $S$ is known.
In my case, $R$ is consisting of a linear combination of finitely unitary conjugations, namely let $r\in R$ and $v\in M$ then $ r(v)=U^\dagger v U$ and $(r+s)(v)=U_1^\dagger v U_1+ U_2^\dagger v U_2$.
What are theorems/facts that can be used in order to determine the annihilator?

So the "unitary conjugations" are from what... $M_n(\mathbb F)$ for some field $F$? That's going to play a large role in "tricks" that are going to be possible with annihilators. You sure this isn't better as a math.stackexchange question?

You also mention "the torsion module."  Usually this refers to "the subset of $M$ with nonzero annihilators" but it is not a submodule for many rings. Of course, the annihilator always exists, and I would understand if that's what you meant in this case.

@rschwieb The unitary conjugations are precisely from the unitary group over the complex numbers, thank you for pointing this out.
Yes, I mean non-zero annihilators, exactly. So my ring elements need not be zero rings.

So, $U$ are just usual unitary finite dimensional matrices here.

I think i need to be sure what ring and what module you are talking about. I think for "finite unitary conjugations" to make sense you might be working in the group algebra $\mathbb C[G]$ where $G$ is the unitary group of a finite dimensional vector space $V$, and $M=V$.  Then you are asking about the annihilator in $\mathbb C[G]$? of a particular element in $V$ ?

Could be, I also considered it from a group algebraic point of view. So, basically, the ring I am talking about is the subring of the space of endomorphisms of $V$ induced by the unitary adjoint representation (or conjugation, some understand under adjoint representation something different) of a group $\mathrm{GL}_n$. So basically, For $r\in R$ we can write $r=\sum_G \alpha_i \pi(g_i)$ for $\pi(g_i)(v)=U_i v U^\dagger_i$ for $G\subset \mathrm{GL}_n$ (GL over the complex numbers, my complex number symbol doesn't work idk). And in $R$ I am looking for the annilitator on $S\subset M$

And it is well known that the ring is a natural extension of the group algebra you mentioned. It is said "$$\tilde{\pi}: \mathbf{C}(G)\rightarrow End (V) , \sum_G \alpha_i g_i \rightarrow \sum_G \alpha_i \pi(g_i)$$, $\pi\rightarrow \tilde{\pi}$ sets up a bijection between the representations of $G$ and the modules over $\mathbf{C}(G)$, preserving equivalence and irreducibility". (this is from a book)

@rschwieb I hope this makes it easier. Hopefully there are some tools now that can be used to classify how my adjoint representations have to be in order to be part of the annihiliator of a known submodule $S\subset M$.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
